# GridView is hiding after Row Deleting Event

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am using GridView Row command Event for deleting row from Gridview, I have added RowDeleting Event of gridview,
but after deleting the GridView is getting hide.
Below is my code

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
       if (!Page.IsPostBack){
LoadData()//Here I am databinding the Grid
}
}

private void LoadData()
{
var data=MyClass.GetRecords();//it returns  DataTable
dg.DataSource=data;
dg.DataBind();
}
protected void dg_RowCommand(Object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
    if(e.CommandName =="del")
    {
        //Delete Records
        dg.DataBind();
    }

}

public void dg_RowDeleting(Object sender, GridViewDeleteEventArgs e)
{
    dg.DataBind();
}
```

Comment: Do you mean the data is all gone?

Comment: where is the datasource??

Comment: @PandaZhang Yes you can say so, but when I refresh the page the GridView appears again

Comment: @VigneshKumar I just posted the methos where issue is arising

Comment: @SyedSalmanRazaZaidi Post the full code.This error is due to Datasource

Comment: Do you mind post the complete code? because it seems that you are not setting the new datasource to your gridview.

Comment: I have posted the updated code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is you are missing DataSource after deleting the rows.

Try this

```
protected void dg_RowCommand(Object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
    if(e.CommandName =="del")
    {
        //Delete Records
       LoadData();
    }

}

public void dg_RowDeleting(Object sender, GridViewDeleteEventArgs e)
{
    LoadData();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The GridView does not show any records because you do not assign a DataSource to it before calling DataBind in `dg_RowDeleting`.

You need to reassign the `DataSource` before calling `DataBind` anew, because it is not set again on a PostBack.

So a typical approach for the Delete part of your `dg_RowCommand` method would be:

1. Identify the row that is to be deleted. Remove the row from the database.
2. Reload the data from the database.
3. Assign the data to the `DataSource` property.
4. Bind the GridView by calling `DataBind()`.

For steps 2-4 you will be able to call your `LoadData` method from `dg_RowCommand`. You only need to implement `dg_RowDeleting` if you do not implement the deletion yourself but want to do something when a row is deleted.